# Can someone explain this chained templates instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

```
class close_queue
{};

class dispatcher
{
    queue* q;
    bool chained;

    dispatcher(dispatcher const&)=delete;
    dispatcher& operator=(dispatcher const&)=delete;

    template<
        typename Dispatcher,
        typename Msg,
        typename Func>
    friend class TemplateDispatcher;

    void wait_and_dispatch()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            auto msg=q->wait_and_pop();
            dispatch(msg);
        }
    }

    bool dispatch(
        std::shared_ptr<message_base> const& msg)
    {
        if(dynamic_cast<wrapped_message<close_queue>*>(msg.get()))
        {
            throw close_queue();
        }
        return false;
    }
public:
    dispatcher(dispatcher&& other):
        q(other.q),chained(other.chained)
    {
        other.chained=true;
    }

    explicit dispatcher(queue* q_):
        q(q_),chained(false)
    {}

    template<typename Message,typename Func>
    TemplateDispatcher<dispatcher,Message,Func>
    handle(Func&& f)
    {
        return TemplateDispatcher<dispatcher,Message,Func>(
            q,this,std::forward<Func>(f));
    }

    ~dispatcher() noexcept(false)
    {
        if(!chained)
        {
            wait_and_dispatch();
        }
    }
};

class receiver
{
    queue q;
public:
    sender operator()()
    {
        return sender(&q);
    }
    dispatcher wait()
    {
        return dispatcher(&q);
    }
};

template<typename PreviousDispatcher,typename Msg,typename Func>
class TemplateDispatcher
{
    queue* q;
    PreviousDispatcher* prev;
    Func f;
    bool chained;

    TemplateDispatcher(TemplateDispatcher const&)=delete;
    TemplateDispatcher& operator=(TemplateDispatcher const&)=delete;

    template<typename Dispatcher,typename OtherMsg,typename OtherFunc>
    friend class TemplateDispatcher;

    void wait_and_dispatch()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            auto msg=q->wait_and_pop();
            if(dispatch(msg))
                break;
        }
    }

    bool dispatch(std::shared_ptr<message_base> const& msg)
    {
        if(wrapped_message<Msg>* wrapper=
           dynamic_cast<wrapped_message<Msg>*>(msg.get()))
        {
            f(wrapper->contents);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return prev->dispatch(msg);
        }
    }
public:
    TemplateDispatcher(TemplateDispatcher&& other):
        q(other.q),prev(other.prev),f(std::move(other.f)),
        chained(other.chained)
    {
        other.chained=true;
    }

    TemplateDispatcher(queue* q_,PreviousDispatcher* prev_,Func&& f_):
        q(q_),prev(prev_),f(std::forward<Func>(f_)),chained(false)
    {
        prev_->chained=true;
    }

    template<typename OtherMsg,typename OtherFunc>
    TemplateDispatcher<TemplateDispatcher,OtherMsg,OtherFunc>
    handle(OtherFunc&& of)
    {
        return TemplateDispatcher<
            TemplateDispatcher,OtherMsg,OtherFunc>(
                q,this,std::forward<OtherFunc>(of));
    }

    ~TemplateDispatcher() noexcept(false)
    {
        if(!chained)
        {
            wait_and_dispatch();
        }
    }
};

class bank_machine
{
    messaging::receiver incoming;
public:
    bank_machine():
    void run()
    {
        try
        {
            for(;;)
            {
                incoming.wait()
                    .handle<verify_pin>(
                        [&](verify_pin const& msg)
                        {
                        }
                        )
                    .handle<withdraw>(
                        [&](withdraw const& msg)
                        {
                        }
                        )
                    .handle<get_balance>(
                        [&](get_balance const& msg)
                        {
                            msg.atm_queue.send(::balance(balance));
                        }
                        )
                    .handle<withdrawal_processed>(
                        [&](withdrawal_processed const& msg)
                        {
                        }
                        )
                    .handle<cancel_withdrawal>(
                        [&](cancel_withdrawal const& msg)
                        {
                        }
                        );
            }
        }

    }

};
```

The code above is a snippet from

> [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://livebook.manning.com/book/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition/appendix-a/50).

and I was wondering if someone can explain, what looks like, chained template instantiation inside bank_machine::run()? Why is it that we can we have a long chain of `handle<some_type>( ...).handle<some_type>( ...).handle<some_type>( ...)` . If you could point me to some resources and also correct any missuses of nomenclature I would appreciate it.

Cheers!

Comment: Where is `template< typename Dispatcher, typename Msg, typename Func> TemplateDispatcher` defined? That's where most of the work appears to be

Comment: @MooingDuck sorry, forgot to include it. I edited the code snipped and added it in

Comment: please edit your title to be in the form of a question about your code! it does not currently describe what you're asking and it's unlikely that anyone else with your problem will be able to find this with your title

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that we can we have a long chain of `handle<some_type>( ...).handle<some_type>( ...).handle<some_type>( ...)`?

For the same reason that you can chain any operator, e.g.

```
a + b + c + ...
```

works, so long as `a + b` returns an object that can be used as the left-hand side of `operator+` with `c` as the right hand side.

In your example

```
handle<some_type>(...)
```

must return an object that has a member access operator `.` that can be invoked on it, where the member itself can be a `handle<some_other_type>` that can then be invoked, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I studied this example code snippet as well and used it in some of my own projects so I wanted to understand it in depth. This my best bet:
Everytime you call

```
handle
```

on the temporary dispatcher-object constructed by

```
incoming.wait()
```

a temporary object of type TemplateDispatcher is created. The magic happens in the destructor:
the last object to be created will be destroyed first and this will trigger the call to

```
wait_and_dispatch()
```

This makes the current thread of execution which is executing this line of code wait for a message to arrive at the message queue (it will sleep, besides spurious wakeups, as the code for dequeueing messages involves condition_variables and associated mutexes). If a message arrives, the thread of execution will check if it is able to deal with the message type and else, if this is not the case, delegate the call to the previously chained TemplateDispatcher or dispatcher-object. When this call is resolved, the destruction of the temporary objects will conclude and due to the

```
for(;;)
```

the thread will continue to wait for incoming messages in the same manner, again, until a close_queue-message arrives at the queue and will trigger an exception thrown in the temporary dispatcher-object's code, exactly in:

```
dispatcher::dispatch()
```

The TemplateDispatcher-objects created by calls to

```
handle
```

will not deal with close_queue-message objects and will therefore delegate any objects of this type to their predecessor in the call chain (dispatcher-class should be the only class that can deal with close_queue-objects) and it will finally be delegated to the dispatcher-object which will then trigger the exception.

The delegation of message objects that are not handled by a certain TemplateDispatcher-objects (identified by the template parameters on instantation in the handle-calls) are delegated to the previous TemplateDispatcher-object in the method

```
dispatch
```

of class TemplateDispatcher. A dynamic cast is used to determine if the current TemplateDispatcher-object has to deal with the arrived message.